# Elastic BeanStalk loading configuration from another region failed

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have uploaded a saved configuration file in a BeanStalk application in a region to another BeanStalk application in another region.
While loading that config I got an error

> Stack named 'awseb-e-sme7w3eym3-stack' aborted operation. Current
>   state: 'CREATE_FAILED' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to
>   create: [AWSEBLoadBalancer]
>
> Creating load balancer failed Reason: Property Listeners cannot be
>   empty Any idea about this issue ?

See the config file

```
AWSConfigurationTemplateVersion: 1.1.0.0
EnvironmentConfigurationMetadata:
  DateCreated: '1580272974000'
  DateModified: '1580273310143'
  Description: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
EnvironmentTier:
  Name: WebServer
  Type: Standard
OptionSettings:
  AWSEBAutoScalingGroup.aws:autoscaling:updatepolicy:rollingupdate:
    MaxBatchSize: '1'
    MinInstancesInService: '1'
    RollingUpdateEnabled: true
    RollingUpdateType: Health
  AWSEBAutoScalingLaunchConfiguration.aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:
    EC2KeyName: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmHigh.aws:autoscaling:trigger:
    UpperThreshold: '60'
  AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmLow.aws:autoscaling:trigger:
    BreachDuration: '2'
    LowerThreshold: '25'
    MeasureName: CPUUtilization
    Period: '1'
    Statistic: Maximum
    Unit: Percent
  AWSEBLoadBalancerSecurityGroup.aws:ec2:vpc:
    VPCId: vpc-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  AWSEBV2LoadBalancerListener.aws:elbv2:listener:default:
    ListenerEnabled: false
  AWSEBV2LoadBalancerListener443.aws:elbv2:listener:443:
    SSLCertificateArns: arn:aws:acm:us-east-2:xxxxxxxxxxx:certificate/xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
  AWSEBV2LoadBalancerTargetGroup.aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default:
    HealthCheckPath: /rest/account/ping
    MatcherHTTPCode: '200'
    Port: '80'
    Protocol: HTTP
  aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:
    IamInstanceProfile: aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role
    SecurityGroups:
    - sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxx
  aws:ec2:instances:
    InstanceTypes: t2.small
  aws:ec2:vpc:
    ELBSubnets: subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    Subnets: subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING: jdbc:mysql://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?user=xxxxxxxx&password=xxxxxxxxxxx&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
    aws.accessKeyId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    aws.secretKey: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    com.aws.secretManger.secret.name: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    com.aws.secretManger.secret.region: us-east-2
    com.decsond.loggly.token: xxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxx
    com.decsond.metakey: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/XXX==
    com.decsond.mode: debug
    com.decsond.server.db.environment: aws
    com.decsond.server.dpBinaryColumn: xxxxxxxxxxxx
    com.decsond.server.environment: xxxxxxxxxx
    com.decsond.server.type: pms
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:tomcat:jvmoptions:
    JVM Options: -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Dmvel.disable.jit=true -Ddrools.permgenThreshold=0
    Xms: 512m
    Xmx: 1024m
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:
    LoadBalancerType: application
    ServiceRole: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:healthreporting:system:
    SystemType: enhanced
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:managedactions:
    ManagedActionsEnabled: true
    PreferredStartTime: SAT:03:01
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:managedactions:platformupdate:
    InstanceRefreshEnabled: true
    UpdateLevel: minor
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:xray:
    XRayEnabled: true
  aws:elbv2:listener:443:
    DefaultProcess: default
    ListenerEnabled: true
    Protocol: HTTPS
    Rules: ''
    SSLPolicy: ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08
Platform:
  PlatformArn: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-2::platform/Tomcat 8.5 with Java 8
    running on 64bit Amazon Linux/3.3.1
```

Any idea about the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is that you are referencing objects in the region from where the config was saved from.

Is this the first EB application / environment in the new region?

If it is, it's worth first creating a test application and environment, using the features you want ... that will give EB a chance to create all the region specific behind-the-scenes magic it relies on.